# Human Tasks in WSO2 Micro Integration 7.X

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I could not find any documentation about Human Tasks in WSO2 Micro Integration 7.X.
Is it still available. If yes - where can I find a documentation.
If not - which tools do you use for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Human Tasks are not available in the 7xx series. You have to use the latest product in 6xx series (ie Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0) if you want to use Human Tasks